# Setting full screen brightness in an Android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, screen-brightness, window-managers

I'm using this method to set the screen to full brightness.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
private void setFullBright() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
        windowParams.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(windowParams);        
    }
}
```

If I want the full brightness to be set on the entire life of the Activity's screen, is the onCreate method the best place to call it?

Is there an XML flag that can achieve this? Something like *android:keepScreenOn="true"* that mirrors the functionality of adding *WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON* in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For everyone who's trying to achieve the same in a `DialogFragment`. Applying the params to `getActivity().getWindow()` won't help since the window of the `Activity` is not the same as the window the `Dialog` is running in. So you have to use the window of the dialog - see following snippet:

```
getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL;
getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

And to answer the original question:
No there is no way to set this via XML.

Answer (score 20):

Put these lines in the oncreate method of all java files which are used to view pages,

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

This will solve your problem, Happy coding...

Comment: You can also use the the constant [`WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTESS_OVERRIDE_FULL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) instead of `1.0F`. There is also `BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE` to reset the brightness to the device setting, and `BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF` to turn the brightness all the way down.

Comment: @Bryan: "BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL" not "BRIGHTESS_OVERRIDE_FULL"

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin version with constant instead of float: (not for Dialogs)

```
private fun setScreenBright() {
    with(window){
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
        attributes = attributes.also { 
            it.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL
        }
    }
}
```