# Change Brightness fragment dialog

Tags: java, android, fragment, dialogfragment

I try to change brightness when dialog fragment opened,i insert this code on oncreate() but it change only for one second.

```
    try {
        curBrightnessValue = Settings.System.getInt(
                getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
        layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
        getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(layout);

    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In main fragment it works

Comment: Try to do it in `onResume` to see if there is a difference

Comment: Thanks for reply, i already tried, but have the same result

Comment: Did you look at this thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for reply, i can't ask system permission to my users, not is  a best solution.

Comment: I try to use ` onActivityResult()` from my caller fragmet ad try to set brightness before call a dialog fragment and reset after call it, but when dialog fragment opened it ignore the brightness setted by parent fragment. Can you help me?

Comment: I found the problem:  `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MppTheme_FullScreenDialog);`  I set a full-screen dialog with this code, if i remove it brightness work fine. How i can set in other way the full-screen fragment dialog?

Comment: I had the same problem. Check the solution at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49731557/896002. It worked for me